# Div Overlaps, how to display it vertically?

Tags: html

this code overlaps two div, (using html only)how do i display these vertically like this: https://i.stack.imgur.com/Mq5om.jpg

```
<html>
<body>
<title> Flag Ship Devices </title>
<div>
<object border="2" width="400" height="250" data="D:\Project1\FinalResource\iphonex.jpg" align="left" > 
<img src="D:\Project1\FinalResource\iphonex.jpg">
</object>
<object align="left">
<ul>
<h2> <a href=""> iPhone X (Matte Black, 64GB) </a> </h2> <br>
<li> <p>Price &#x20b9;83499</p> </li>
</object>
</div>
```

[enter image description here][1]

### Mi A1 (White, 64GB)

Price ₹13999

Comment: <object align="left">.... change to right

Comment: i want it to display like this https://i.stack.imgur.com/Mq5om.jpg

Answer (score 1):

Please, take a look and see if this helps you.

Also, I suggest you to use [bootstrap](https://getbootstrap.com/), it's a very good framework to this kind of need.

```css
.product_container{
  width: 100%;
  margin-bottom: 10px;
  display: flex;
}
```

```html
<html>
<body>
<title> Flag Ship Devices </title>
<div class="product_container">
  <object border="2" width="400" height="250" data="D:\Project1\FinalResource\iphonex.jpg" align="left" > 
    <img src="https://placehold.it/400x250"/>
  </object>
  <object align="right">
    <ul>
      <li><h2> <a href=""> iPhone X (Matte Black, 64GB) </a> </h2> <br></li>
      <li> <p>Price &#x20b9;83499</p> </li>
    </ul>
  </object>
</div>
<div class="product_container">
  <object border="2" width="400" height="250" data="D:\Project1\FinalResource\iphonex.jpg" align="left" > 
    <img src="https://placehold.it/400x250"/>
  </object>
  <object align="right">
    <ul>
      <li><h2> <a href=""> iPhone X (Matte Black, 64GB) </a> </h2> <br></li>
      <li> <p>Price &#x20b9;83499</p> </li>
    </ul>
  </object>
</div>
```

Comment: thank you for your time,i am just using html, how do i do it with out bootstrap or css?

Comment: no CSS? what kind of site is this? inline-css is also CSS...
if you don't to use external file, copy the CSS that I used, and paste in the inline of the element, like in the `div`... `style="width: 100%;
  margin-bottom: 10px;
  display: flex;"`